Ctrl + F5 not starting application as expected
I have installed Python and Visual Studio Code (VSC), installed Python extensions for VSC and Postman. Now I want to run my project by hitting Ctrl + F5.
The Terminal shows all messages as if I typed python main.py, but when I am checking the first microservice at localhost:8001, it says it is unable to connect. Running the project by typing python main.py produces the same export, but I am able to connect to localhost:8001 and other microservices.
From what I read, I am supposed to have a launch.json file, that should encompass all run and debug configurations. My launch.json looks like this:
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
    {
      "name": "Python: main.py",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\main.py",
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
  ]
}

Aside from the fact that the editor is recommending to replace "python" with "debugpy", nothing changed the behaviour described above. I read somewhere that VSC is automatically deciding whether you are running a project without or with debug and that the user has just to have a configuration for the debug case.
I also tried something that a friend recommended with a "compounds" section in launch.json, but neither did I understand, why I should do that, nor did it solve anything.

What should my launch.json look like?
Is there a way to automatically start the virtual environment of a project when hitting (Ctrl + ) F5?
How can I test - maybe with a minimal working example - whether I found the correct launch.json?


so did you switch to debugpy?

I tried both variants and they are both not working as expected. I have been very naive to believe that a plain install will run out of the box. ;)
